# How controller a VideoView in Fragment when I pressed onBackpressed in parent Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-videoview, onbackpressed

I have an Activity (A) that contains a ViewPager which calls a Fragment to present information to the user (this Activity A is called from an Activity B). My Fragment contains a VideoView which plays an MP4 with GIF behavior. My problem is when I want to return to Activity B, since when doing a Finish () in the onBackpressed in Activity A, for a few milliseconds the videoView looks over the contents of Activity B.

**UPDATE**

I discovered that the problem is due to the ViewPage.
It happens that when I'm in position 0, calling the onBackPressed method works everything ok. But when the onBackPressed method is called from another position, closing the Activity momentarily shows the VideoView of the previous position.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() != 0) {

        //I don't know what to do here

    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please finish your call when you Back pressed.

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (/--logic--/) {
        finish();
    }
}
```